# Convert Bit-field to list in python

Tags: python, list, bit-fields

I'm not a dev... 
And wouldlike  a function, to convert a bit value, into a list of integer :

let say I have the following possible bits :
1
2
4
8

I would like a function, 
bit2list(7) that would give back (1;2;4) 
or
bit2list(9) should give back (1;8)

Can someone Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point would be the `bin` function:

```
>>> bin(7)
'0b111'
>>> bin(9)
'0b1001'
```

From there, it's pretty easy to transform the bit strings into the indices you want.

Comment: Many thanks, what should be the best way, an indexof() ?